# why datatable child rows showing duplicated records?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have datatable which is showing [**details rows**](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). It is working fine for first time but when I click on second or third child row then it shows duplicated rows, I mean the rows which were in 1st child rows.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                    "url":"{{ route('admin.requestReport') }}",
                    "dataType":"json",
                    "type":"POST",
                    "data":{"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"}
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "className":      'details-control',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },  
                { "data": "counter" },
                { "data": "start_date" }
            ],
            /* "order": [[1, 'asc']], */
            searching: false
        } );

        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        } );
    } );
```

I did `console.log()` and found the problem, but i need to guideline to solve it. The problem I found which is here

```
else {
    // Open this row
    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
}
```

I did `console.log(row.data())` which is also passing the previous clicked rows into function.

I would like to request you kindly guide me how can I pass the data() of single row into function. I would like to appreciate. Thank you so much.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Vel how to create it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/okmbw3dx/1/  update with static data.

Comment: Can you post your HTML please

Comment: @karthickj25 Sure